# Kendo Multi-select in cascading scenario unable to populate initial values

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik for MVC and trying to get the multi-select to populate with the initial values in an Edit scenario.

```
  <script>

                function filterProducts() {
                    return {
                        manufacturerId: $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ManufacturerId").val()
                    };
                }

                function onManufacturerChange(e) {                                   
                    var v = e.sender.dataItem().Value;
                    $.post("@Url.Action("GetCascadeProducts", "Components")", { manufacturerId: v }, function (result) {
                    var grid = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts").data("kendoMultiSelect")
                    grid.setDataSource(result)
                });                        
                }

                function InitialPopulate(manId) {                                                           
                    $.post("@Url.Action("GetCascadeProducts", "Components")", { manufacturerId: manId }, function (result) {
                        var grid = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts").data("kendoMultiSelect")
                        grid.setDataSource(result)

                    });



                }


                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.control-datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();
                    var m = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ManufacturerId").val();
                    InitialPopulate(m);
                });




        </script>





                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ManufacturerList, "Manufacturer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceBulletinItem.ManufacturerId)
                                     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-md-6 form-control" })
                                     .Filter("contains")
                                     .DataValueField("Value")
                                     .DataTextField("Text")
                                     .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.ManufacturerSelectList)
                                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:70%;" }).Events(e =>
                                     {
                                         e.Change("onManufacturerChange");
                                     })
                                     )
                    </div >
                </div >


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductList, "Product", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.ServiceBulletinItem.ApplicableProducts)
                              .AutoClose(false)
                              .DataTextField("ProductName")
                              .DataValueField("ProductId")
                              .Placeholder("Select products...")

                        )




                    </div>
                </div>
```

I'm trying to populate the manufacturer drop down and the Product multiSelect.     The ApplicableProducts item is an IEnumerable representing the ProductId's of all those previously selected and I know that when I select the manufacturer and it calls the GetCascadeProducts controller method it will return back a collection of ProductId and ProductName for all the manufacturers products of which those productId is the ApplicableProducts property should exist.

On document.ready I can call the InitialPopulate method with the manufacturerID which will populate the multiSelect items but can't seem to populate the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt get the binding working correctly so ended up using

```
                    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                              .Name("ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts")
                              .AutoClose(false)
                              .DataTextField("ProductName")
                              .DataValueField("ProductId")
                              .Placeholder("Select products 2...")
                              .AutoBind(false)                                  
                            )
```

and then on the using the following code on document ready to make an ajax call to populate the manufacturer and product controls

```
function PopulateProductsInitial(manId) {
                    $.post("@Url.Action("GetCascadeProducts", "Components")", { manufacturerId: manId }, function (result) {

                        var grid = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts").data("kendoMultiSelect")
                        grid.setDataSource(result);

                        var s = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_Id").val();

                        $.post("@Url.Action("GetSBProducts", "ServiceBulletins")", { Id: s}, function (result) {
                            var arr = [];
                            result.forEach(function (element) {
                                arr.push(element.ProductId);
                            });

                            var grid = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts").data("kendoMultiSelect")
                            grid.value(arr);                            
                        });



                });
                }
                }

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    //Populate Initial Values
                    PopulateProductsInitial($("#ServiceBulletinItem_ManufacturerId").val());
                    $('#YourButton').click(SendForm);

                });
```

The problem then became sending the selected items back to the controller when the edit was complete which again seemed convoluted because the control was not bound and therefore I had to make an Ajax call to submit the data.

```
function SendForm() {
                    var items = $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ApplicableProducts").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();

                    //Manipulate into ServiceBulletinViewModel for the save
                    var data = {
                                 Id: $("#ServiceBulletinItem_Id").val(),
                                 ServiceBulletinItem: {
                                     Id: $("#ServiceBulletinItem_Id").val(),
                                     ManufacturerId: $("#ServiceBulletinItem_ManufacturerId").val(),
                                     IssueDate: $('#ServiceBulletinItem_IssueDate').val(),
                                     Heading: $('#ServiceBulletinItem_Heading').val(),
                                     Details: $('#ServiceBulletinItem_Details').val(),
                                     Url: $('#ServiceBulletinItem_Url').val(),
                                     SelectedProducts: items
                                 }
                                }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/ServiceBulletins/Edit',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        success: function (result) {
                            //Your success code here..
                            if (result.redirectUrl != null) {
                                window.location = result.redirectUrl;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR) {
                            if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                                alert("Value Not found");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

It all seemed a lot more convoluted than any of the demo's that teleriks and I couldnt find any good examples of binding from remote sources which looked similar.

As the binding is convention based I'm wondering if its possible to simplify the ajax calling for the post functionality with the correct naming of the controls so that I can simply get the selected items on the multiselect control or if the ajax post is the way to go.